# Flash between page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, dom-events

I am getting a white flash between page loads on Chrome that is making transiitions look clunky. I have made most images sprites (ones that I could), lowered image size, minified the CSS, loaded the CSS in the right order (i think), added to the `.htaccess` for cache (see below) and put as much JS in the footer as possible (it is build in Wordpress so some plugins I dont think I can control on how they load). Anyone have any ideas? The pages dont take long to load, just get a flash. I would like the header to not reload and just the body (which I have the CSS fade one) fade in and out. So could the files be loading out of order to cause a flash in chrome? What else should I do to optimize it?

```
# BEGIN Expire headers
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2592000 seconds"
# END Expire headers
```

[This is the site. Its after the age verify](http://watkinsdistributing.com)

Comment: I didn't see a flash.

Comment: Not quite related to your question, but your delivery is incredibly slow. 724ms rendering time for what could be static content will yield a very bad search page ranking, just saying.

Comment: @Kay I guess my questions is there anyway to optimize it more? And is the flash caused by loading files in wrong order

Comment: Since you’re loading new pages the view will obviously redraw (and the empty white base-page that is shown prior to the render will cause the “flash” you refer to). If you want the header to stick between page-loads, you’ll either have to use AJAX to update your content or trap the content inside an iframe.

Comment: Thanks @tobi. I will look into using AJAX to load the page content

Answer (score -1):

Try compressing the images
The site takes very long to load

Comment: Try this plugin, it helped me

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/

And reply to the post letting us know if this was the solution :)

Comment: See the waterfall diagram in e.g. Firebug: The problem is not that to much data is transmitted. The page is slow b/c the PHP rendering is slow. Probably PHP is used in CGI mode.